# Destructuring Nested Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to play around ES6 and trying to convert a ES5 function to ES6.

**ES5:**

```
const ResponseData = {
    items: [{name: 'Matt'}]
}

function getName(ResponseData) {
    let itemDetails = ResponseData && ResponseData.items && ResponseData.items[0];
    return itemDetails.name;
}
```

However, I am not sure how to access items[0] in ES6 destructuring.

Here's my attempt:

```
function getItemES6(ResponseData) {
 const { items : item = []   } = ResponseData;
 return item;
}
```

This is pretty much giving me item array, how do I get items[0] and check for .name using ES6?

Little confused with destructuring. Can someone enlighten?

Comment: I think its 'const { items: [firstItem]} = Responsedata'. If that's correct ill write it in an answer :)

Comment: Not needed anymore hahah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can destructure nested objects and arrays, add add empty object/array as default to get `undefined` if value doesn't exist:

```js
const ResponseData = { items: [{name: 'Matt'}] };

const getItemES6 = ({ items: [{ name } = {}] = [] }) => name;

console.log(getItemES6(ResponseData));
```

Comment: My response data looks like this

`
var RespData = {
 items: [{name: 'Matt'}]
}
`

How can I get name if present? Or undefined if key is not present?

Answer (score 2):

You destructure objects as such:

`const {
   key: yourVar = 'defaultVal'
} = obj`

Arrays are similar, but instead of referencing keys, you reference the elements themselves:

`const [
firstElem,
secondElem
] = arr`

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    b1: 'a'
  }
};

const objWithArr = {
  a: 1,
  b: [{
    key: 5,
  }, {
    key: 6
  }]
}

const {
  b: {
    b1: b1Val = 'default',
  } = {},
} = obj;

const {
  b: [{
      key: firstKey,
    } = {},
    {
      key: secondKey,
    } = {}
  ] = [],
} = objWithArr;

console.log(b1Val);
console.log(firstKey);
console.log(secondKey);
```